# Problem running MySQL >8.0 sqlMessage:" 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',"

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trunning to run node with mySQL and get the following error:
" sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',"

I have googled around at found the solution to be:
"ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'"

But WHERE to put this command? I have downloaded the mysql shell and get the following error:
"SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

I have tried the mysql workbench under queries and get the following output:
"09:13:58   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'   0 row(s) affected   0.015 sec

But it doesnt help.

Comment: Perhaps you need to type `\sql` to switch to SQL mode. Do you have another MySQL tool you're familiar with?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to modify the query. Maybe replace ‘root’ with the login name the software uses. And also remove @‘localhost’ part in case you’re connecting from another host.

Something like

```
ALTER USER 'app' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: Hi, May I know what is 'app', 'mysql_native_password' and 'password' ?